# How to set mysql port for Drupal and Drush

Tags: drush, database

My site was running fine with the following default setting in settings.php file:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => ''
```

Then I created a separate mysql instance on another port:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '123'
```

But this does not affect drupal - it still connects to the old db on default port!

With the following settings drupal connects to the new db, but now I can`t make archive-dumps with drush. Drush reports an "Unknown MYSQL server host error".

```
'host' => 'localhost:123',
'port' => ''
```

Answer (score 1):

For the port configuration in settings.php you can do by following(in example i used MYSQL in 33066) and the value of port is integer not string:

```
//D6 DB config
$db_url = 'mysqli://mysqluser:mysqlpassword@dbhost:33066/yourdb';

//D7 DB config
$databases = array('default' => array('default' => array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'yourdb',
  'username' => 'mysqluser',
  'password' => 'mysqlpassword',
  'host' => 'dbhost',
  'port' => 33066 )));
```

Comment: That is what I tried.

> But this does not affect drupal - it still connects to the old db on default port!

Comment: Drush only get configuration from /sites/default/settings.php. Did you place your settings file in /sites/yoursite.abc/settings.php?

Comment: Drush is using /sites/yoursite.abc/settings.php, at least for archive-dump command, where I tell it which site to archive. And yes, I am changing only mysite/settings.php. With 'localhost' it is working, with 'localhost:portnum' - not.